# How do I structure and build a tree hierarchy in nav-tabs while keeping my business logic out of the view

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an MVC C# project using Razor and Bootstrap.

It consists of:

- Projects
- Roles
- People

**Partial View:**

```
<ul class="white nav nav-tabs tabs-left">
@foreach (var role in ViewBag.Roles)
{
    @role.Name
    <!-- It would be great to get this code out of the view and into a class somewhere -->
    foreach (var person in Model.ToList().Where(c => c.Role.Name == role.Name))
    {
        <li>
            <a href="#person_@(person.PersonID)" data-toggle="tab">
                @person.Person.Contact.FullName
            </a>
        </li>   
    }

}
</ul>
```

**This partial generates this nav-tab list:**

[image: This partial generates this nav-tab list]
[image]

**Partial View Controller:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult List(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var projectsinvolvedwith = db.ProjectsInvolvedWith
                                    .Include(p => p.PaidByProject)
                                    .Include(p => p.Person)
                                    .Include(p => p.Project)
                                    .Include(p => p.Role)
                                    .Include(p => p.Person.Contact);

        projectsinvolvedwith = projectsinvolvedwith.Where(p => p.ProjectID == id);

        ViewBag.Roles = db.Roles.ToList();

        return PartialView("_List", projectsinvolvedwith.ToList());
    }
```

**My issue arrives when there are no results for the inner foreach loop in the partial.**

It generates a header and nothing below as expected, but I would like to add a single marker to empty sections that states that the section is vacant.

Something like this:

[image]

At this point I start moving towards putting an if/else statement in the View that checks whether the section is empty or not, and I know that the business logic should be kept behind the scenes.

**How do I structure this so that I can keep the logic out of the View?  I am thinking that I would need to build a list with 'Role Vacant' inserted into the list where no People exist in the Role**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you approach it from an other way. First create the header with a list item "role varcant" and after that you overwrite it with your script to add content. So if it has content it gets overwritten and if there is nothing to add it keeps the default list item.